# Ajax request not working in Yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I`m trying to execute ajax request, but it returns error function.

Js:

```
cr_day_next.on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'planing/next-day',
            data: {data: 'works'},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(res) {
                alert(res);
                cr_day.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('try again');
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller:

```
public function actionNextDay($data){
        if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax()){
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: can you provide a scree shot of your xhr request body and header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is incorrect. `$data` argument in your action must come from `$_GET`, but you're sending it as `POST`. You should use `$_POST` to get data:

```
public function actionNextDay() {
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        return Yii::$app->request->post('data');
    }
}
```

Or send request as `GET`:

```
cr_day_next.on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?= Url::to(['planing/next-day']) ?>',
        data: {data: 'works'},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            alert(res);
            cr_day.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('try again');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: i have changed my controller (according to your advice with POST), but it still not works

Comment: You should define what "not works" actually mean. Does action returns anything? What HTTP response code do you get?

Comment: Then rewrite your error function to actually return something useful.

Comment: Also, make sure that your URL is correct - see  how it was defined in my GET example.

Comment: You need to read about csrf protection: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-best-practices#avoiding-csrf . And you also have incorrect configuration of error handler component.

Comment: Also i use JQuery plugin OwlCarousel, and when i change url to your example, carousel doesnt loads

Comment: Well, the problem was in csrf-protection. When i turned it off, i got new exception. isAjax() is not a method, but a bool variable. Thanks for all help